# How to add a column to a table and have it displayed as the first column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table `EMP` with 2 columns `ENM` and `EADD`. Now I need to add a column `EMPID` but I want it to be displayed as the first column in the table, like `EMPID, ENM, EADD`.

Comment: You add columns with `alter table amp add empid number` etc. Why do the columns need to be in a particular order? If you really need to, making a column invisible and then visible again moves it to the end of the list for `describe`, although it doesn't physically rearrange the internal structure.

Answer (score 1):

Demo:

```
create table emp
( enm  varchar2(20)
, eadd varchar2(100) );

alter table emp add empid number not null;
```

Describing `emp` gives:

```
Name                            Null?    Type
------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
ENM                                      VARCHAR2(20)
EADD                                     VARCHAR2(100)
EMPID                           NOT NULL NUMBER
```

Make all the columns except `empid` invisible and visible again:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select column_name
        from   user_tab_columns c
        where  c.table_name = 'EMP'
        and    c.column_name <> 'EMPID'
    )
    loop
        execute immediate 'alter table emp modify '||r.column_name||' invisible';
        execute immediate 'alter table emp modify '||r.column_name||' visible';
    end loop;
end;
/
```

and now you have this:

```
Name                            Null?    Type
------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
EMPID                           NOT NULL NUMBER
ENM                                      VARCHAR2(20)
EADD                                     VARCHAR2(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

As William Robertson suggests, using invisible and visible can be used to reorder columns.  However if your table has a lot of fields this method can be obnoxious, especially if you are reordering multiple times during development.

There is always the tried and true method of dropping the table and recreating with the desired order.